# How to use a font installed in your computer, to a web site?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am trying to use Helvetica Neue 55 Light, I have it installed on my computer.
However, it is not showing up on other people's PC's.
So I tried font-facing it from my computer, but I was told there was an issue with the url, that I was using a relative url (to the folder in which the site is contained, I am using Neocities so that folder is not* in my computer, and I don't know how to add the font to such online folder if there are any?) and that I must use an absolute url.

Help? :s

Comment: Can you show the code that refers to the font?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face

Comment: @font-face {
   font-family: HelveticaNeueLT Std Lt;
   src: url('C:\Windows\Fonts');
}

Comment: You need to buy a license for Helvetica Neue 55 Light before you can do this, otherwise you'll be liable for criminal copyright infringement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a font kit.

This site will do it for you: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

However, it will not let you use a copyrighted font. Not all the font files on your computer are authorized for web use, but you can buy the license from the creater (these typically have a high price tag).

Answer (score 2):

If your font is installed locally, specifying where it is on your computer will not allow people to access it from your website. You're going to need to either upload the font files to your hosting server (in this case, Neocities); or, failing that, upload it to another static hosting service, such as dropbox, and specifying the URL of where the file is stored then.

EDIT: You're probably better off not using Helvetica Neue or any Adobe font, unless you're willing to fork out hundreds of pounds for it.

Answer (score 2):

Fonts are licensed differently for desktop use and for web use. If you have it installed on your computer you probably have a desktop license, but likely not a web license. The formats are also different in many cases, so if you have the desktop font it won't work to just put it on your server, and like others have said, you also can't just convert it in some cases without violating the copyright.

MyFonts is one vendor that sells Helvetica Neue Light. If you go to the [buying choices page](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/neue-helvetica/helvetica-45-light/buy.html), you'll see that there are lots of licensing options. Make sure you buy the Webfont option if you want to deliver it online. After you purchase, there should be some instructions on how to use it.

There's actually a really good discussion going on right now about some of the different methods of delivering web fonts. That might be [worth checking out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116682/webfonts-or-locally-loaded-fonts) too.