# Font file is too big

Tags: html, css, font-face

I'm using font-face to load custom fonts. i have a file with 6 types of fonts, loading with base64 url.
The file is huge - 1.5MB.
What is the best solution to add this file to my site?

Comment: couple of solutions: host/import it on google fonts or use a different 'normal' font face.

Comment: useful references possibly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116682/webfonts-or-locally-loaded-fonts

http://www.feedthebot.com/pagespeed/web-font-options.html

Comment: Isn’t the obvious solution to use separate font files rather than base64 encoded data? What is the issue that prevents using that?